# In PHP, Removing first element in CSV String

Tags: php, string, csv

I'm simply looking to take the first csv out of a string, using PHP. Here are a few examples:

- "Sea Bass, Floured Or Breaded, Fried" => "Floured Or Breaded, Fried"
- "Tuna, Fresh, Baked Or Broiled" => "Fresh, Baked Or Broiled"
- "Croaker, Breaded Or Battered, Baked" => "Breaded Or Battered, Baked"

And so on...

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but can you give more information, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Do you already have code that loads the CSV file into memory? If so, would you please post the relevant portion?

Comment: Show the CSV data, because what this is, isn't separating the two elements, which means you want to modify data inside a csv element rather than remove an element.

Comment: As Ben says, how are you populating your string.... if it is from a file, then PHP's fgetcsv() function can simplify things for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$csvArray = explode(",", $csv);
array_shift($csvArray);
$newCsv = implode(",", $csvArray);
```

Comment: You don't need to (and *should not ever*) pass an array (or anything, really) by reference to a *built-in* function unless the function expressly requests a reference.  Besides being [counter-intuitively slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117604/why-is-calling-a-function-such-as-strlen-count-etc-on-a-referenced-value-so-sl), it's previously been a [security risk](http://php-security.org/category/vulnerabilities/index.html) in the PHP core (check out the "interruption" bugs...)

Comment: Won't work if any of the values actually contain a comma, whereas the built in CSV handling functions can handle this

Comment: array_shift does request a reference.

Comment: @Mark Baker: yea true, but that was just a quick solution based on examples he posted.

Comment: `array_shift` works with a reference, but you do not need to expressly create a reference to make it work.  What you'd done is called "call-time pass-by-reference", and is considered such a bad practice that they added an error message just to tell people to stop doing it.

Comment: Yeah, I did notice the error message, which is why I removed it. Thanks for the heads up, though.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or something similar that parses csv, this will take into account any quotation marks and commas in the CSV string. after that you can just array_shift