# Error in hierarchical php function exectuion! What's this?

Tags: php, arrays, function, hierarchical

Why am I getting different outputs through print_r in the following two cases!!? This is a bug in php? Is php unable to execute complex hierarchical functions called inside functions?

```
CASE 1 :
$aa='2,3,4,5,5,5,';
$aa=array_unique(explode(',',$aa));
array_pop($aa);
print_r($aa);

CASE 2 :
$aa='2,3,4,5,5,5,';
array_pop(array_unique(explode(',',$aa)));
print_r($aa)
```

In the first case, the output is an exploded array :

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )
```

In the second case, the output is string :

```
2,3,4,5,5,5,
```

Comment: If your first question is to ask if there's a bug in the tool, the answer is probably no.

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to print *what* output you get.

Comment: @Vishal, edit your question to put the example output in.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the outputs.

Answer (score 7):

This is because `array_pop` alters its input, and you're passing it a temporary variable (not `$aa`).

Note the signature in the documentation: [`array_pop ( array &$array )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) - the `&` means it takes a parameter by reference, and it alters that input variable.

Compare with the other two functions:

[`array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string , int $limit )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

and

[`array array_unique ( array $array , int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

In the first case you update `$aa` with the output of `array_unique()`, and then pass that to `array_pop` to be altered.

In the second case the output of `array_unique()` will be the same, but this temporary value isn't assigned to a variable & therefore it's forgotten after `array_pop` is called.

It's worth noting that in that in PHP (unlike say, C++), [passing by reference is actually *slower* than passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117604/why-is-calling-a-function-such-as-strlen-count-etc-on-a-referenced-value-so-s) and therefore is only ever used to modify the input parameter of a function.

Comment: yes I'm aware that passing by reference is slow, and I rarely use it. Going by default with the case1 above!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you alter variable as in line 2 bs assigning a new value with the assignment operator =