# Benefit of passing by reference? (php)

Tags: php, variables, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP (>= 5.0), is passing by reference faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178328/in-php-5-0-is-passing-by-reference-faster)

I know the use of passing by reference.  I'm wondering specifically is there some resource and/or performance benefit to passing by reference?  Do I keep cleaner memory resources by passing, for instance PDO objects, by reference instead of value?  I think php5 automatically passes objects by reference by default right?

Comment: I believe this question contains two different subjects. You can ask whether it's faster to pass a regular variable by value or by reference, but when passing objects you don't really have such choice.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is an *exact duplicate* of the other question. Sure, he asks about performance, but he also asks about benefits of references in general.

Comment: It's pretty close to the duplicate listed.  Close enough that I would be comfortable closing this.  Not exact, but very similar.  Not sure how i didn't find that. Promise I did my searching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing by reference is faster. PHP5 do pass objects by reference by default. I *think* under PHP 5.3, you still have to do `$obj = &new Object();`, but I could be wrong about that.

PHP5 do not pass array by reference. If you want to modify them in a function, you need to pass by reference.

Passing by value means that every single value is copied. For example, if you pass an array by value, it copies the array to a different memory location and every single element in it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [References Explained](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) and [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) might be of some help.