# php array reference passing to function

Tags: php

I have a question that I cannot find an answer.

I'm constructing a very big array that contain hex values of a file (like `$array[0]=B5` `$array[1]=82` and so on until `$array[1230009]`)

When I create a function to manipulate some offsets in that array and pass the `$array` as reference ( `function parse(&$array) { ... }`) it takes WAY longer than if I pass the array normaly ( `function parse($array) { ... }`) ..

How is that possible ?

PS: Is there any faster way not to use array at all ? Just to use a $string = "B5 82 00 1E ..etc", but I need to track the Offset as i advance in reading hex values as some of this values contains lengths"

Comment: It takes longer to pass the array, or it takes longer to perform your function on the array that you pass?

Also, this is not a RAM efficient means of referencing each byte of a file. You should use strings instead methinks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP (>= 5.0), is passing by reference faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178328/in-php-5-0-is-passing-by-reference-faster)

Comment: it takes like 30 seconds to perform the function on the array (by reference) and 2 second to perform the function on the array by normal passing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some informations that might help in the following article : [**Do not use PHP references**](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

Close to the end of that post, Johannes posts the following portion of code *(quoting)* :

```
function foo(&$data) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++) {
        do_something($data{$i});
    }
}

$string = "... looooong string with lots of data .....";
foo(string);
```

And a part of the comment that goes with it is *(still quoting)* :

> But now in this case the developer tried to be smart and save time by
>   passing a reference. 
> But well, `strlen()` expects a copy. 
>   
> copy-on-write can't be done on references so `$data` will be
>   copied for calling `strlen()`, `strlen()` will do an absolutely simple
>   operation *- in fact `strlen()` is one of the most trivial functions
>   in PHP -* and the copy will be destroyed immediately.

You might well be in a situation like this one, considering the question you are asking...

Comment: EDITED: Ok I understand that now but : How to use strings like $string = "B5 82 00 1E .... etc" ? But I need to perform a login on every hex value and need to keep the offset as I advance in reading it