# update array with a value coming from the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this structure (this is one of the entries):

```
[11] => Array
        (
            [id_cred] => CD000000905
            [gbv_tot] => 482197.51
            [ammesso] => 482197.51
            [tipo] => 1
            [importo] => 0
            [stato] => aperta
        )
```

I loop through it in a foreach to set [importo] to be equal to [gbv_tot] or [ammesso] based on some conditions. I wrote this code but seems not to update the value of the key [importo].

```
foreach($creds as $cred){
    if(($cred['tipo'] == '1')&&($tipo_az == 'conc')){
        //sto elaborando un chirografo in una azione concorsuale quindi prendo il nominale
        if($cred['stato']=='aperta'){
            $gbv_compl = $gbv_compl + $cred['ammesso'];
            $cred['importo'] = $cred['ammesso'];
        }else{
            $cred['importo'] = 0;
        }
    }else{
        //sto elaborando qualcosa d'altro e quindi prendo il GBV
        if($cred['stato']=='aperta'){
            $gbv_compl = $gbv_compl + $cred['gbv_tot'];                 
            $cred['importo'] = $cred['gbv_tot'];
        }else{
            $cred['importo'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is not the right way to do it since I cannot get [importo] to be updated. What am I missing?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15024616/3933332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `foreach($creds as $cred){` `$cred` will not refer to the main `array`. For each iteration it will assign the current element to `$cred`. You need to use the `key` -

```
foreach($creds as $key => $cred){
```

And set the value like -

```
$creds[$key]['importo'] = 'whatever value it is';
```

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

```
foreach ($creds as &$cred) {
```

By using the *reference* you can directly update them. Now -

```
$cred['importo'] = 0;
```

Will change the value of the current element of the main `array`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that since I was in the foreach loop I could omit the key.. Will mark this as solved as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 5):

Change this line,

```
foreach($creds as $cred){
```

to

```
foreach($creds as &$cred){ // pass $cres 's value by reference
```

Now, changes to `$cred` are applied to your array