# Changing element in the for-loop

Tags: php

Here when I don't use `unset()` function and `print_r($color)`, it outputs `YELLOW` as a result. I don't get why it outputs only `YELLOW`?

```
$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
foreach ($colors as $color)  {
    $color = strtoupper($color);
}
unset($color);
print_r($colors); // outputs: Array ( [0] => RED [1] => BLUE [2] => GREEN [3] => YELLOW )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach change original array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values)

Comment: didn't clear your question define which type of output you need

Comment: use `$colors = array_map('strtoupper', $colors);` it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the completion of the foreach loop, $color contains the last element Array , and then is changed to upper case ie it contains "YELLOW". If you print out it's contents using print_r it will output "YELLOW" unless you have already unset it.

What do you want to do? if you want to change each element of the array to upper case, you need to use the following foreach loop:

```
    foreach ($colors as &$color)  {
        $color = strtoupper($color);
    }
    print_r($colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `$color` as a variable. You should define `$color` as an array and store the color value in it.

```
<?php
$colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow');
 $colorArr = array();    
foreach ($colors as $color)  {
    if($color=='yellow'){
     continue;
    }
    $colorArr[] = strtoupper($color);        
}
//unset($color[3]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($colorArr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Note:** put a condition and check if there is color in the loop then continue the loop.

```
if($color=='yellow'){
 continue;// continue the loop without going to assign it in array
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
    [2] => green        
)
```

Comment: no need to use `unnecessary variable` use simple `$color[]` its also work.

Comment: Oaky, @BhargavChudasama thanks, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you unset $color  and not  the entry $colors[3]

if you need  unset the yellow  entry  then

```
unset($colors[3]);
```

otherwise if want unset all the array content then

```
unset($colors);
```