# PHP replace array values inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result array from array_merge and json encode and it look like below:

```
$c=[{"type":"textarea","label":"textarea","Element_Values":"cfgedrgyte","Element_Name":"textarea-201859","Count_Images":0,"req":0},  {"type":"dropdown","label":"dropdownbox","Element_Values":"d2","Element_Name":"dropdown-480200","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"d1","sel":0},{"label":"d2","sel":0}]},
    {"type":"sub-header","label":"section3","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"sub-header-327336","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"checkbox","label":"checkbox","Element_Values":"[\"c1\",\"c2\"]","Element_Name":"checkbox-483738","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"c1","sel":0},{"label":"c2","sel":0}]}, {"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0}, {"label":"r2","sel":0}]},
    {"type":"description","label":"test template is here","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"description-764196","Count_Images":0,"req":0}]
```

If the type is checkbox or radio, get the Element_Values and change the array choices according to Element_Values.

```
{"type":"checkbox","label":"checkbox","Element_Values":"[\"c1\",\"c2\"]","Element_Name":"checkbox-483738","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"c1","sel":0},{"label":"c2","sel":0}]}
```

Above, Element Values are c1 and c2. Then I need to change sel=1.
That is

```
"choices":[{"label":"c1","sel":1},{"label":"c2","sel":1}]}
```

Here another type radio is:

```
{"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0},{"label":"r2","sel":0}]}
```

And the output should be:

```
{"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0},{"label":"r2","sel":1}]}
```

I did the following code:

```
$c=json_decode($c);
foreach($c as $kc=>&$vc)
{
    if( $vc['type']=="checkbox" || $vc['type']=="radio")
    {
       $Val=$vc['Element_Values'];
       $choices=&$vc['choices'];
       foreach($choices as $key=>&$val)
       {
           if($val['label']==$Val)
           {
               $val['sel']=1;
           }
           unset($val['sel']);
       }
    }
}
echo json_encode($c);
```

I know it is a simple thing I am missing. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach change original array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go (I put some comments in to point out changes):

```
$c=<<<JSON
[{"type":"textarea","label":"textarea","Element_Values":"cfgedrgyte","Element_Name":"textarea-201859","Count_Images":0,"req":0},  {"type":"dropdown","label":"dropdownbox","Element_Values":"d2","Element_Name":"dropdown-480200","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"d1","sel":0},{"label":"d2","sel":0}]},
    {"type":"sub-header","label":"section3","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"sub-header-327336","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"checkbox","label":"checkbox","Element_Values":"[\"c1\",\"c2\"]","Element_Name":"checkbox-483738","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"c1","sel":0},{"label":"c2","sel":0}]}, {"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0}, {"label":"r2","sel":0}]},
    {"type":"description","label":"test template is here","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"description-764196","Count_Images":0,"req":0}]
JSON;

//add second argument here
$c=json_decode($c,true);
//by refrence here
foreach($c as $kc=>&$vc)
{
    //in array is prettier, if you want to expand on this it will be easier
    //instead of another OR you just add another element, a switch would work too
    if( in_array($vc['type'], ["checkbox","radio"]))
    {
       $Val=$vc['Element_Values'];
       //This is double encoded.  Sometimes its an array sometimes it's not
       //So normailize it 
       if(gettype($Val) == 'string'){
            //decode it if it's not an array
            $Val = json_decode($Val);
            //normalize to array
            if($Val && !is_array($Val)) $Val = [$Val];

       }
       $choices =& $vc['choices']; //by refrence here

       foreach($choices as $key=>&$val)
       {

           if(in_array($val['label'],$Val)) //Use in array
           {
               $val['sel']=1;
           }
          // unset($val['sel']); whats this for? it just unsets the above
       }
    }
}
print_r($c);
echo json_encode($c);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => textarea
            [label] => textarea
            [Element_Values] => cfgedrgyte
            [Element_Name] => textarea-201859
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => dropdown
            [label] => dropdownbox
            [Element_Values] => d2
            [Element_Name] => dropdown-480200
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
            [choices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => d1
                            [sel] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => d2
                            [sel] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => sub-header
            [label] => section3
            [Element_Values] => -
            [Element_Name] => sub-header-327336
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => checkbox
            [label] => checkbox
            [Element_Values] => ["c1","c2"]
            [Element_Name] => checkbox-483738
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
            [choices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => c1
                            [sel] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => c2
                            [sel] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => radio
            [label] => radio
            [Element_Values] => "r2"
            [Element_Name] => radio-824113
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
            [choices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => r1
                            [sel] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => r2
                            [sel] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => description
            [label] => test template is here
            [Element_Values] => -
            [Element_Name] => description-764196
            [Count_Images] => 0
            [req] => 0
        )

)
```

Json

```
[{"type":"textarea","label":"textarea","Element_Values":"cfgedrgyte","Element_Name":"textarea-201859","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"dropdown","label":"dropdownbox","Element_Values":"d2","Element_Name":"dropdown-480200","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"d1","sel":0},{"label":"d2","sel":0}]},{"type":"sub-header","label":"section3","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"sub-header-327336","Count_Images":0,"req":0},{"type":"checkbox","label":"checkbox","Element_Values":"[\"c1\",\"c2\"]","Element_Name":"checkbox-483738","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"c1","sel":1},{"label":"c2","sel":1}]},{"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0},{"label":"r2","sel":1}]},{"type":"description","label":"test template is here","Element_Values":"-","Element_Name":"description-764196","Count_Images":0,"req":0}]
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a6c7ac19e655dea92a0f0febbaa7d4fc9de1320)

**UPDATE**

This element is always double encoded, in the example data.  `$Val=$vc['Element_Values'];`  It was missing the radio button the first time I did it.  So now I have it decode it if its not an array and then check that the result is an array.  The radio value was this `"\"r2\""` Which when not decoded has an extra set of quotes `'"r2"'`, but is a string when decoded.  So we don't want to worry about 2 data types so we can just make that an array...

Cheers

**BONUS**

Instead of an if here:

```
if( in_array($vc['type'], ["checkbox","radio"]))
```

I changed this to in_array as it's easier to add to,

```
if( in_array($vc['type'], ["checkbox","radio","drowdown"]))
//instead of
if( $vc['type']=="checkbox" || $vc['type']=="radio" || $vc['type']=="drowdown")
```

but a switch is good too:

```
switch($vc['type']){
    case 'checkbox':
    case 'radio':
      //... Code ...
    break;
}
```

Then if you want to add code for other types:

```
switch($vc['type']){
    case 'checkbox':
    case 'radio':
      //... Code ...
    break;
    case 'dropdown':
       //... Code ...
    break;
}
```

Using In array or a switch is just a bit cleaner IMO.

Comment: This code works fo the type checkbox, but for the type radio its still not changing the sel value. {"type":"radio","label":"radio","Element_Values":"\"r2\"","Element_Name":"radio-824113","Count_Images":0,"req":0,"choices":[{"label":"r1","sel":0},{"label":"r2","sel":1}]}

Comment: Thats ok with radio type. I can json encode it as well. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Zendie - it's fixed for radio buttons now.

Comment: Sure, I didn't realize that it had the extra quotes at first...  Hard to read the JSON so I included the output as an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the original array, all the variables from it should be set as a reference.

```
foreach($c as $kc=> &$vc)
{
       $choices= &$vc['choices'];
       foreach($choices as $key=>&$val)
```

If you don't want to use a reference variable, you should change the value from the top

```
foreach($choices as $key=> $val)
    $c[$kc]['choices'][$key]['sel']=1;
```

Comment: I want to change the original array. But only want to change sel value 0 to 1 according to Element_Values. I have edited my code according to this. But the sel key is missing may because I use unset

Comment: Yes, remove unset

Comment: I did comment unset line.. But the value is not changing

Comment: You should check the input data, nothing is matched with the conditions now.