# Pushing data into arrays stored in another array

Tags: php, arrays, list

How can i add values to an array that is being contained by another array?

In the example code below, i am trying to add the string 'yellow' to both the arrays stored by `$arr` to form `[ [ 'blue',yellow'] , ['green','yellow'] ]`

In the first foreach loop, the word yellow has been successful pushed into the contained array which can be seen when i print out the array $key however

when i were to print the $arr out in the final foreach loop the yellow that i appended is gone

```
    $arr = array(array("blue"),array("green"));

    foreach ($arr as $key)
    {
        array_push($key,"yellow");
        print_r($key);
    }
    foreach ($arr as $key)
    {
        print_r($key);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($arr as &$key)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reference on your foreach like so **&$key** to save your modification :

PHP make a copy of the variable in the foreach, so your **$key** is not actually the same as the one from your previous array.

From @[Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values) :

> & passes a value of the array as a reference and does not create a new
>   instance of the variable.

So just do :

```
$arr = array(array("blue"),array("green"));

foreach ($arr as &$value)
{
    $value[]='yellow';
    print_r($value);
}
foreach ($arr as $value)
{
    print_r($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) no key approach

```
$arr = [["blue"], ["green"]];
foreach ($arr as &$value)
       $value[]='yellow';        
print_r($arr);
```

Here is [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) with key approach

```
$arr = [["blue"], ["green"]];
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
       $arr[$key][]='yellow';        
print_r($arr);
```

Here is another approach using [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$arr = [["blue"], ["green"]];
array_walk($arr, function(&$item) {
    $item[] = "yellow";
});
print_r($arr);
```

Here is the same thing with [array_map](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php)

```
$arr = [["blue"], ["green"]];
$arr = array_map(function($item) {
    $item[] = "yellow";
    return $item;
}, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output for all examples

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => yellow
        )

)
```

And finally some performance tests [speed](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f71c9f79b225a454e4fc36781e4d071bda9f154c) and [memory_usage](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14a5f12296c95a3520de5e96eaa15bbb82e31779)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_map for this. See the below code for example.

```
$a = [["blue"],["green"]];

$b = array_map(function($n) {
    $n[] = "Yellow";
    return $n;
}, $a);

print_r($b);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. Edited my answer.