# use foreach on declared but empty array

Tags: php, foreach

To limit the use of `[xx]` in my code I would like to do something `C/C++` style :

```php
$nbItem = 30;
items = array($nbItem);

foreach ($items as $i => $item){
    $item = new Entity();
    $item->setToto();
    // do other stuff
}
```

Of course it didn't work, is there a typo or is just impossible in `php` ?

**Note**

I know how to do the same with a `for ($i ....)` loop so my question is specifically on `foreach`

Comment: your array `$items` is not an empty array

Comment: You use `$item` for various things (the value from the `foreach` and the new `Entity()`)

Comment: Show us an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-fill.php) method. e.g in your code

```
$nbItem = 30;
items = array_fill(0,$nbItem,0);

foreach ($items as $i => $item){
    $item = new Entity();
    $item->setToto();
    // do other stuff
}
```

In your code, you are trying to push the 30 into array which is at 0 index, ultimately it has a size of 1

If you dont want to assign 0 to every index you can use [range](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.range.php) e.g

```
$nbItem = 30;
items = range(0,$nbItem);

foreach ($items as $i => $item){
    $item = new Entity();
    $item->setToto();
    // do other stuff
}
```

i would recommend this solution cz its neater

Comment: I come from the documentation. 
Sadly the definition isn't like `array_fill($num, $value=0, $start_item=0)` So I'm force to set them all. thx

Comment: I prefer the second. For future answer consider adding the links to the documentation when you present functions it's easier for noobs as me

Comment: **very important comment** if you intent to use this solution and change the variable. make sur that the value is passed by reference such as :
`foreach(items as &$item)`. The explainations are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024638/6734243)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to declare array size as you suggested. If you **MUST** use `foreach` you can try this way:

```
$items = array_fill(0, $nbItem, null);

foreach($items as $i => &$item) {
    $item = new Entity();
    $item->setToto();
    // do other stuff
}
```

But I strongly discourage you to use this solution. Just do it in a `for` loop:

```
$items = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $nbItem; $i++) {
    $item = new Entity();
    $item->setToto();
    // do other stuff

    $items[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: You have no Idea how many instructions I need to set and how painful it is for my eyes to see so many `[x]` :)

Comment: @PierrickRambaud check updated answear with `for` example. The is only one `[]` more.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to pay attention regarding the code you posted.

`array(30)` does not produce an array with 30 items but one array having `30` as its only element.
For an array with 30 items you can use [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

`foreach ($items as $i => $item)` -- `$item` is not a reference but a copy of an element of the array.
You then store something else in `$item` (`$item = new Entity();`) and the array seems to be used only to count to `30`.

If your intention is to use the array only to count to `30` then the easiest way is to generate the array using [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
foreach (range(1, 30) as $i) {
  $item = new Entity();
  $item->setToto();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `for` loop be [sightly] better? Foreach seems to be using each value (or maybe key) when in the exampled loop the value of the counter is not significant.

Comment: the foreach loop is faster in any case. I just wanted to initialize an array of 30 empty slots.