# How to iterate and add a "random" key/value to an existing object using hasMany

Tags: php, laravel

Using the `with` method, I do not see anything near, [on the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships), as to what I want to accomplish. Possible?

```php
// bars is a hasMany() association

public function getFoo($id, $fooId)
{
    return $this
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('fooId', $fooId)
        ->with([
            'one',
            'two',
            'bars' => function($queries) {
                foreach ($queries as $key => $query) {
                    $queries[$key]['extraKey'] = 'extraValue'; // extrakey can be any name I want it to be.
                    // $query['extraKey'] = "extraValue";
                }
            }
        ])
        ->first();
}
```

I'm following [Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values) how to loop and modify but I'm not seeing `extraKey` in the returned data.

Do I have perform this action in the controller? Seems messy if that's the only way. I thought I could so these actions within the model itself.

I expect to see:

```php
foo->bars[0]->extrakey;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `Bar` model:

```
class Bar extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function getExtraKeyAttribute()
    {
        return 'extraValue';
    }

    // ...
}
```

Additionally, if you want to include this value in the `toArray` output, add it the protected `$appends` property of your model:

```
class Bar extends Model
{    
    protected $appends = ['extra_key'];
```

Comment: Ok... I expect to get back the value from the loop .

Comment: Do you mean inside this loop `foreach ($queries as $key => $query)`? That's not possible. In this function you can access the [query builder to restrict](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) the eager-loaded relations for bars. At this point there isn't any data loaded yet.

Comment: Ok I'm no longer going this route but I do found your answer useful for other things so I'll upvote. Many thanks.