# Edit json item by id

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit json item property value by id, but it deleted all content exept the specific item i updated.

```
$projectsArr = json_decode(file_get_contents("../db/memory.json"), true);

foreach($projectsArr['memory'] as $mydata) {
    if($mydata['id'] == $_POST['id']) {
      $mydata['approved'] = true;
      $json = json_encode($mydata, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      file_put_contents('../db/memory.json', $json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only store the `json` back into the file after editing the data

```php
<?php
    foreach($projectsArr['memory'] as &$mydata) {
        if($mydata['id'] == $_POST['id']) $mydata['approved'] = true;
    }

    $json = json_encode($projectsArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    file_put_contents('../db/memory.json', $json);
}
```

Also note that a `foreach` will create a temporary copy of the data, hence I use `&` to create a reference to the original data. More information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024638/446594)