# Query field added but not visible in template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my Symfony project I try to append new array key-value pair into the result I am rendering to twig template file.
It has some odd behaviour.

```
$posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->getPage($listType, $page, $pageSize);

foreach ($posts['data'] as $post) {
    $post['destinationName'] = $this->destinationService->getDestinationName($posts['data']);
}

return $this->render('posts.html.twig', [
    'posts' => $posts['data'],
]);
```

Trough this `getPage()` method in my controller I get paginated list of my data. Which is working. Than in the foreach() I am appending new key-value pair to that array.

When dumping `$posts` I get: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yogXx.png)

When dumping `$post` from foreach, this is the output I get: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1obhA.png) As you can see, the last pair, `destinationName` is added.

Then when dumping the same result in my twig template I get: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4vqx.png)

As you can see, when template is rendered, it disappears.

My question is, that maybe it's overwritten? But I can not see why. Do I maybe need to append that filed in my query builder? But as I am adding the field after result is rendered, I suppose that should not be the case..

Any hints?

Maybe getDestinationName() will show something:

```
public function getDestinationName($posts)
{
    foreach ($posts as $postsData) {
        foreach ($postsData as $post) {
            $destinationName =  $this->getDestinationDetails(
                $post->getDestinationId(),
                $post->getAccountTokenId()
            );
            return $destinationName['full_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP foreach change original array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values)

Comment: Not sure, because I do not need to change original value, just to add another one key-value pair.  @DarkBee

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to mixe array with object and then add other stuff.
The best thing you could do is this :

```
$posts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->getPage($listType, $page, $pageSize);

$destinationNames = [];
foreach ($posts['data'] as $post) {
    $destinationNames[$post->getPostId()] = $this->destinationService->getDestinationName($posts['data']);
}

return $this->render('posts.html.twig', [
    'posts' => $posts['data'],
    'destinationNames' => $destinationNames,
]);
```

I suppose here that `$post->getPostId()` is your unique identifier, if not, replace by the right identifier

And in your template you could do something like :

```
{% for post in posts %}
    // do your stuff
    {{ destinationNames[post.id] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I get Call to a member function getPostId() on array as the structure is  like I posted on IMAGE no. 2. $post from foreach dump() in the post above. @jean-max

Comment: As you can see it has [0] => @jean-max

Comment: If the array always contain one element, you can do `$post[0]->getPostId()`

Comment: You are great! Thank you!  @jean-max