# Remove stop words from searchstring in PHP

Tags: php

I am facing problems with a PHP function for optimizing a search string for a MySql query.

I need to find an entry which look like 'hobbit, the' by searching for 'the hobbit'.

I thought about cutting the articles (in Germany we have 'der', 'die' and 'das') if they have a trailing space out of the search string.

My function looks like:

```
      public function optimizeSearchString($searchString)
      {
        $articles = [
          'der ',
          'die ',
          'das ',
          'the '
        ];
    
    
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
//only cut $article out of $searchString if its longer than the $article itself
          if (strlen($searchString) > strlen($article) && strpos($searchString, $article)) {
            $searchString = str_replace($article, '', $searchString);
            break;
          }
        }
    
        return $searchString;
      }
```

But this doesn't work...

Maybe there is a nicer solution using regular expressions?

Comment: This test `strlen($searchString) > strlen($article)` is totally useless, remove it. `strpos` may return 0 that is interpreted as false. You must write `strpos(...) !== false`. Instead of making tests, replace directly. in this way you parse the string only once.

Comment: The  advantage of using `preg_replace` here is to avoid false positive using word boundaries to delimit words, and to remove all of them in one pass using an alternation. The pattern is not difficult, a quick regex tutorial will solve the problem.

Comment: I tried `$optimizedString = preg_replace("/(der\s|die\s|das\s|the\s)/", '', $searchString);` but this seems not to work...

Comment: "not to work" is not an information, what happens (error message, same string, other)?

Comment: i try to search for the string 'der hobbit' and it should search for 'hobbit' because the part 'der ' should be replaced with the empty string '' but the result is empty. If I search for 'hobbit' there are results

Comment: @bambamboole See [an idea with splitting](https://eval.in/425363) and removing *stopwords*.

Comment: Take care to return `$optimizedString` and not `$searchString`

Comment: [Its working for me](https://eval.in/425367). Can you be more specific for your errors and inputs along with expected outputs

Comment: Ok, all solutions seems to work, but I don't know which part of the whole legacy code breaks it.

Comment: Can update to the code you have that breaks?

Comment: Did an edit on title. Please check if ok, else undo!

Comment: u did well! thx a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution provided by @Jonny 5 seems to be the best for my solution.

Now I use a function like this:

```
  public function optimizeSearchString($searchString = "")
  {
    $stopwords = array(
      'der' => 1,
      'die' => 1,
      'das' => 1,
      'the' => 1);

    $words = preg_split('/[^-\w\']+/', $searchString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if (count($words) > 1) {
      $words = array_filter($words, function ($v) use (&$stopwords) {
        return !isset($stopwords[strtolower($v)]);
      }
      );
    }

    if (empty($words)) {
      return $searchString;
    }

    return implode(" ", $words);
  }
```

The new solution of Jonny 5 would work also, but I use this one, because I'm not that familiar with regex and I know whats going on :-)

Comment: Great that helped! I also posted an answer with another solution :]

Answer (score 5):

1.) To just remove *one stopword* from **start or end of the string** by using [regex like this](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3kC5/2):

```
~^\W*(der|die|das|the)\W+\b|\b\W+(?1)\W*$~i
```

- `~` is the [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)
- `^` the caret [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches start of the string
- `\W` (upper) is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for a character, that is not a *[word character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899/3110638)*
- `(der|die|das|the)` alternation `|` in first parenthesized [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `\b` matches a *[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*
- At `(?1)` the pattern of first group is pasted
- `$` matches right after the last character in the string
- Used `i` *(PCRE_CASELESS)* [flag](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). If input is utf-8, also need `u` *(PCRE_UTF8)* flag.

[Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Generate the pattern:

```
// array containing stopwords
$stopwords = array("der", "die", "das", "the");

// escape the stopword array and implode with pipe
$s = '~^\W*('.implode("|", array_map("preg_quote", $stopwords)).')\W+\b|\b\W+(?1)\W*$~i';

// replace with emptystring
$searchString = preg_replace($s, "", $searchString);
```

*Note* that if `~` delimiter occurs in the `$stopwords` array, it also has to be escaped with a backslash.

[PHP test at eval.in](https://eval.in/425404), [Regex pattern at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3kC5/2)

---

2.) But to **remove stop words anywhere in the string** how about splitting into words:

```
// words to be removed
$stopwords = array(
'der' => 1,
'die' => 1,
'das' => 1,
'the' => 1);
# used words as key for better performance

// remove stopwords from string
function strip_stopwords($str = "")
{
  global $stopwords;

  // 1.) break string into words
  // [^-\w\'] matches characters, that are not [0-9a-zA-Z_-']
  // if input is unicode/utf-8, the u flag is needed: /pattern/u
  $words = preg_split('/[^-\w\']+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

  // 2.) if we have at least 2 words, remove stopwords
  if(count($words) > 1)
  {
    $words = array_filter($words, function ($w) use (&$stopwords) {
      return !isset($stopwords[strtolower($w)]);
      # if utf-8: mb_strtolower($w, "utf-8")
    });
  }

  // check if not too much was removed such as "the the" would return empty
  if(!empty($words))
    return implode(" ", $words);
  return $str;
}
```

See [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/425745), [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/MP0Ia2)

```
// test it
echo strip_stopwords("The Hobbit das foo, der");
```

> Hobbit foo

This solution will also remove any punctuation besides `_` `-` `'` because it's imploding remaining words with space after removing the *common words*. The idea is to prepare the string for a query.

Both solutions don't modify the case and will leave the string if it only consists of *one stopword*.

*Lists of common words*

- [Most common words in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English) <sup>Wikipedia</sup>
- [Most frequent words in German language](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_h%C3%A4ufigsten_W%C3%B6rter_der_deutschen_Sprache#Die_hundert_h.C3.A4ufigsten_W.C3.B6rter_im_Deutschen) <sup>Wikipedia</sup>
- [MySQL: English full-text stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)
- [Default English stopwords list](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords)
- [List of German stopwords](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords/german)

Comment: Could you please explain why you are passing `$stopwords` by reference in the `array_filter` closure  in your second code? I ask because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845530/4946451) post about value vs. reference performance. Wouldn't it be better to pass by value here?

Answer (score 3):

This is what i do.

```
public function optimizeSearchString($searchString) {
    $wordsFromSearchString = str_word_count($searchString, true);
    $finalWords = array_diff($wordsFromSearchString, $stopwords);
    return implode(" ", $finalWords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a different version using `array_diff`, which @Yashrajsinh Jadeja also did. I added a third parameter 'strcasecmp' to ignore case and made the input an array using a simple word tokenizer.

```
//Search string with article
$searchString = "Das blaue Haus"; //"The blue house"

//Split string into array. (This method is insufficient and doesn't account for compound nouns like "blue jay" or "einfamilienhaus".)
$wordArray = preg_split('/[^-\w\']+/', $searchString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

var_dump(optimizeSearchString($wordArray));

function optimizeSearchString($wordArray) {
  $articles = array('der', 'die', 'das', 'the');
  $newArray = array_udiff($wordArray, $articles, 'strcasecmp');
  return $newArray;
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(5) "blaue"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "Haus"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function optimizeSearchString($searchString)
{
        $articles = (
          'der ',
          'die ',
          'das ',
          'the '
        );


        foreach ($articles as $article) {
         //only cut $article out of $searchString if its longer than the $article itself
          if (strlen($searchString) > strlen($article) && strpos($searchString, $article)) {
            $searchString = str_replace($article, '', $searchString);
            break;
          }
        }

        return $searchString;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you just copied the question code and reposted it. At a minimum, you should provide context as to what this code does differently or how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm borrowing from code posted by [Keith Morris on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/keithmorris/4155220).  You can customize your own list of words, or adjust the one already made, very easily by adding/removing/updating the array of common words.

```
<?php
    function removeCommonWords($input){
        $commonWords = array('a','able','about',...);
     
        return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);
    }
    
    print(preg_replace('/[\s+]+/', ' ', removeCommonWords("This is my Title!  It is about Cats, Dogs, and Furry Animals.")));
?>
```

The output for `"This is my Title!  It is about Cats, Dogs, and Furry Animals."` from up above is: `"This Title! It Cats, Dogs, Furry Animals."`.

[**Full Working Demo Online**](https://3v4l.org/1e4me)