# Simpler than $this->variableObject

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, global-variables, this

I'm really sick of typing `$this->database` or `$this->otherVarOrFunc` every time I call something in my controller/model/wherever else.
 Is there some sort of OOP trick to have for example `$database` instead of `$this->database` in every function of my controller?

I have well defined structure of BaseController on MVC level and BaseObject for everything else class related. These two contains 5 to 20 object variables (depends on app size ) and I would be much more satisfied if typing `$this->` wasnt required.

Does it have negative impact on overall performance? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of each class function, you could define a local variable for the function that references to the `$this`.
For example:

```
class a {
    function __construct() {
        $this->aa = "hey";      
    }
    public $aa;
    public function aaa() {
        $ab = &$this->aa;
        $this->aa = "hey1";
        echo $ab;
    }
}
$b = new a;
$b->aaa();
```

Now throughout the function, use `$ab` instead of `$this->aa`

Comment: Well, sure, but it requires to write 1 more line per function per variable. I'm not really sure whether it'll speed proceess up...

Comment: I don't think using references would slow anything down, but it saves you from typing the `$this->` each tme

Comment: You're right! I have additional question: If I inicialize new objects from class with $this->database and counstruct of new object has ($database) as parameter, should I go for $obj = new someObject($db) or new someObject(&$db)? What should be faster and by how much?

Comment: It seems you don't gain performance by passing a reference. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845530/3548935).

Comment: In new php versions, instances are passed to functions by reference by default.