# Why Reference to Reference Not Working Inside Foreach Loop?

Tags: php

In below code if I uncomment(use) Approach 2 & comment(disable) Approach 1, why Approach 2 is not modifying the `$arr`? What is are the alternatives to Approach 2?

```
$val = 'OOOOOO';
$arr = ['a' => 'AAA', 'b' => 'BBB'];

echo print_r($arr, true) . '<br>'; //Array ( [a] => AAA [b] => BBB )


// Approach 1 start - THIS WORKS
$arr['a'] = &$val;
$arr['b'] = &$val;
// Approach 1 end

// Approach 2 start - DOES NOT WORKS
// foreach ($arr as $ky => &$vl) {
//     $vl = &$val;
// }
// Approach 2 end

echo print_r($arr, true) . '<br>'; //Array ( [a] => OOOOOO [b] => OOOOOO )
```

Comment: Could you add what `print_r` is printing in both cases so we can understand what's not working here ?

Answer (score 2):

In the `foreach` loop you can't modifiy your `$vl` without a reference. Since it's not the original variable.

[In PHP (>= 5.0), is passing by reference faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178328/in-php-5-0-is-passing-by-reference-faster)

What you can do is something like this:

> ```
> foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
>   /* your condition*/
>   $array[$key] = $some_value;
> }
> ```

Therefore in the `foreach` you can use `$value` (that can be modified without consequences) but you can also modify directly your array. Modifications that would be kept outside of the `foreach`

Comment: its possible to modify my array in my foreach loop because its passed by reference see this `$ky => &$vl`

Comment: Yes you can use reference to modify your `array` inside the `foreach`.
I gave you an alternative to your Approach 2.
I might not have understood where your issue is :x

Comment: I updated my answer to state that i'm talking when not using reference, you're right

Answer (score 1):

found that in PHP you can't reference to reference.
found with this code:

```
$val = 'OOOOOO';
$b = 'DEFAULT';

$bb = &$b;
$bb = &$val;

echo $b; // prints: DEFAULT
```

Found solution for me: Approach 3

Approach 3 (pass by reference foreach loop) is faster than Approach 4 (pass by value foreach loop) (same as Gregoire Ducharme answer):

```
// Approach 3 start
foreach ($arr as $ky => &$vl) {
    $arr[$ky] = &$val;
}
// Approach 3 end

// Approach 4 start
foreach ($arr as $ky => $vl) {
    $arr[$ky] = &$val;
}
// Approach 4 end
```

**Performance Data (tested on array with long text, 1000000 loops):**

Tested 5 times using Approach 3 (By Reference):

Time: 0.32825803756714,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.33496713638306,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.33242797851562,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.35326600074768,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.33251810073853,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Tested 5 times using Approach 4 (By Value):

Time: 0.36558699607849,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.38936495780945,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.42887806892395,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.44330382347107,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672

Time: 0.49368786811829,
Memory Peak Usage: 596672